# Изучение значений обьекта

Tags: javascript, объекты, property

Подскажите пожалуйста почему в данной задаче, не создаются дубликаты значений в объекте.

```js
function aclean(arr) {

  // этот объект будем использовать для уникальности
  var obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // разбить строку на буквы, отсортировать и слить обратно
    var sorted = arr[i].toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''); // (*)
    obj[sorted] = arr[i]; // сохраняет только одно значение с таким ключом
  }

  var result = [];

  // теперь в obj находится для каждого ключа ровно одно значение
  for (var key in obj) 
    result.push(obj[key]);

  return result;
}

var arr = ["воз", "киборг", "корсет", "ЗОВ", "гробик", "костер", "сектор"];
alert( aclean(arr) );
```

Comment: Присвоили Вы сначала свойству `obj["взо"]` значение `"воз"`, а потом ему же - значение `"ЗОВ"`. Какие дубликаты?

Answer (score 1):

У объекта полей с одинаковым именем могут быть только один, у ваш значение полей перезаписывается по несколько раз, как и указано в комментах кода!